# How can I ignore many endpoints in Skylight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, profiler

[Skylight](https://www.skylight.io/) allows you to ignore a list of endpoints by specifying them in your `skylight.yml` (see [Ignoring heartbeat endpoints](https://docs.skylight.io/getting-set-up/#agent-configuration-general-options-ignoring-heartbeat-endpoints)). But this list doesn't support wildcards and I have a *lot* of endpoints I want to ignore-- what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution-- create a Rake task to dynamically generate the list of endpoints you want to ignore:

```
task generate_ignored_endpoints_list_for_skylight: :environment do
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  ParentController.descendants.flat_map do |controller_class|
    controller_class.action_methods.map do |method_name|
      "#{controller_class.name}##{method_name}"
    end
  end.each do |name|
    puts name
  end
end
```

This will work well if the endpoints you want to ignore are grouped under a parent controller (e.g. `Admin::ApplicationController` if you're using [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate)).